# Ошибка " Неверное преобразование из ''char" в "char*" "

Tags: c++

ошибка:

> " Неверное преобразование из ''char" в "char*" "

как это можно исправить? В программе нужно вывести книги определенного автора

```cpp
использую библиотеку: "string.h"
void b::task()
{

    char a[50];

    gets(a);

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

if ((strcmp(arr[i].getM(),a))==0) - с этой строчкой проблема 

    arr[i].output();
}
```

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

1. У тебя компилятор не понимает, меньше чего должен быть инициализатор i в цикле for.
2. У тебя компилятор не понимает, где начинается цикл for, надо следующей строчкой открыть фигурные скобки, а где ты предполагаешь его окончание надо закрыть фигурные скобки. Тоже самое с конструкцией if.

Comment: (2) - Фигурные скобки можно не писать.